# Let $f(x)$ be continuous from $[0, +\infty)$ to $ [0, +\infty)$, and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, continuity

Prove there exists some $a>0$ such that the series $\sum_nf(an)$ diverges.

I think it can be useful to partition $[0, +\infty)$ on $[n, n+1)$ and choose some $a_n$ for every $n$. But I can't understand how to build $a$ from $a_n$. Also I think integral Koshie trapping is useful.

Comment: " integral Koshie trapping" ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon sorry, it is not trivial to translate from Russian :) I meaned "Integral test for convergence"

Comment: not a_n. an is right!!!

Comment: @GabrielRomon: I guess it's  ‘Cauchy’ which is meant.

Comment: You say "series"; shouldn't it be "sequence"?

Comment: @zhw. yes, probably

Comment: As it stands, it is false. Just take $f\equiv 1.$

Comment: so, series is right

Comment: You don't require $f$ to be decreasing ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon yes, I do not require.

Comment: but for decreasing f this is obviously

Comment: unaccept the question, it is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer is **incorrect**, see the comments below.

Let $A>0$. There exists $M>0$ such that $\int_0^M f(x) dx > 3A$. Since the integral diverges we may suppose WLOG that $f(M)>0$. Since $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[0,M]$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any tagged partition of $[0,M]$ with mesh $\leq \delta$, $$\left|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(t_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i)-\int_0^M f(x)dx\right|\leq A$$
Consider $a<\delta$ and the partition $(0,a,\ldots,\lfloor \frac Ma \rfloor a,M)$ tagged at $(a,\ldots,\lfloor \frac Ma \rfloor a,M) $ which has mesh $\leq a$. Thus 
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor \frac Ma \rfloor} f(na)a + f(M)\left(M-\lfloor \frac Ma \rfloor a\right) -\int_0^M f(x)dx\right|\leq A$$
and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor \frac Ma \rfloor} f(na)a\geq 2A-af(M)$$
Choosing $a<\min( \delta, \frac{A}{f(M)})$ yields $$\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor \frac Ma \rfloor} f(na)a\geq A$$
so the series $\sum_{n\geq 1} f(na)a$ diverges, and so does $\sum_{n\geq 1} f(na)$.

Comment: It seems to me that there are some subtleties which are not taken into consideration. First, your solution does not address the possibility that $\delta$ may depend on $M$. So, if it happens that $\delta = \delta(M)$ decreases to $0$ as $M\to\infty$, then you cannot address a single $a > 0$ that works for arbitrarily large $M$. Second, we do not know whether $A/f(M)$ is bounded away from $0$. Indeed, for $f(x) = e^{x^2}$, we can show that $\left( \int_{0}^{M} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x\right)/f(M) \to 0$ as $M\to\infty$. This again invalidates the choices of $a > 0$ that works for large $M$.

Comment: @SangchulLee I understand my mistake. $a$ should not depend on $A$. Have you found a working proof ?

Comment: Honestly I haven't thought about it enough. One thing I can show is that $\int_{a}^{b} \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(nx) \right)\,\mathrm{d}x = \infty$ for all $[a,b]\subset(0,\infty)$. But I am not sure this together with the continuity of $f$ is enough to conclude.

Comment: @SangchulLee please take some time to ponder on this problem, I find it very intriguing and would love to see a solution !