# $\forall a > 0$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(na)$ is convergent. Prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Hi can you help me solve this exercise? Thanks. Let $f: [0;+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be nonnegative and continuous function. Suppose $\forall a > 0$  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(na)$ is convergent. Prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx$ is convergent. I tried to solve it by using the Riemann sum, but for fixed a it doesn't work. I have no other ideas.

Comment: That statement is equivalent to the question in [Let $f(x)$ be continuous from $[0, +\infty)$ to $ [0, +\infty)$, and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3229975/let-fx-be-continuous-from-0-infty-to-0-infty-and-int-0). – Unfortunately, that question has an accepted but (admittedly) wrong answer.

Comment: That seems not too far from a well known application of the Baire theorem: if $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $\forall a > 0, f(na) \rightarrow_{n \rightarrow \infty} 0$ then $f(x) \rightarrow_{x \rightarrow \infty} = 0$, right?

Comment: Where does this problem come from ?

Comment: From Riemann sum, it's enough $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(\frac{n}{m}) / m$ is finite. Unfortunately we can't switch summation and limit, and I don't know if it's rigid enough estimation to be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. > Let $f$ be a non-negative function such that there exists numbers $a<b$ verifying 
   >   $$\tag{*}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac 1n\int_{an}^{bn}f(u)du<+\infty.   $$
   >   Then $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(u)du$ is finite.

   Indeed, without loss of generality, assume that $a=1$ (do the substitution $at=u$ and replace $f$ by $x\mapsto f(ax)$). Pick a number $c$ such that $1<c^2<b$ and define $c_N:=\left[c^N\right]$. Then 
   $$b\left(c_N+1\right)>bc^N>c^{N+2}\geqslant c_{N+2}.$$
   In the series involved in (*), cut the index of summation according to $c_N+1\leqslant n\leqslant c_{N+1}$ in order to get 
   $$ 
   \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac 1n\int_{n}^{bn}f(u)du\geqslant \sum_{N\geqslant 0}\sum_{n=c_N+1}^{c_{N+1}} \frac 1n\int_{c_{N+1}}^{b(c_N+1)}
   f(u)du\geqslant \sum_{N\geqslant 0}\frac{c_{N+1}-c_N}{c_{N+1}}\int_{c_{N+1}}^{ c_{N+2}}
   f(u)du$$
   hence the series $\sum_{N\geqslant 0} \int_{c_{N+1}}^{ c_{N+2}}
   f(u)du$ converges, which proves the claim.
2. So what would be helpful would be uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(nx)$ at least on a non-empty interval. Define 
   $$
     F_N:=\left\{x\geqslant 0, \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f(nx)\leqslant N\right\}.
     $$

   - For each fixed $N$, the set $F_N$ is closed since it can be written as the 
     intersection of the sets $G_m$, where $G_m=\left\{x\geqslant 0, \sum_{n=1}^{m}f(nx)\leqslant N\right\}$ which is the inverse image of  the closed set $[0,N]$ by the continuous function $x\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^{m}f(nx)$.
   - By assumption, $[0,\infty)=\bigcup_{N\geqslant 1}F_N$.

   Consequently, by Baire's theorem, one of the $F_N$, say $F_{N_0}$ has a non-empty  interior and contains an interval $[x_0-2r_0,x_0+2r_0]$ (we also assume that $r_0\lt x_0$).
3. For each $x\in [x_0-r_0,x_0+r_0]$, $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f(nx)\leqslant N_0$ hence integrating on this interval and switching the series and the integral (without worrying, since everything is non-negative), we get 
   $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_{x_0-r_0}^{x_0+r_0}f(nx)dx\leqslant 2N_0r_0.$$
4. In each integral, do the substitution $u=nx$ and apply item 1. to $a=x_0-r_0$ and $b=x_0+r_0$.