# Series $\sum f(nx)$ converges a.e. for integrable $f$

Tags: real-analysis

I am facing a problem about proving the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(nx)|$ converges for a.e. $x$, where $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Besides, I would like to ask further about another series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(x+n)|$. I **guess** it should also converge a.e. when $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, based on the result on Riemann integral,. However I also failed to prove it.

My first thought to these two problems are similar: assuming there's a set $E$ with positive measure s.t. the series diverges, but I didn't figure out what's the next step. Do you have some ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you want to examine $$\sum_{\color{red}n = 1}^{\infty} \lvert f(nx) \rvert$$ ?

Comment: Can't help recall a sort of [the converse](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3236636).

Comment: Thank you all for pointing out the mistake and adding related materials! I have corrected the question~

Answer (score 4):

There are two questions here. The second is easier. We can assume $f\ge0$. On a bounded interval  of the form $[a,a+1]$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{a}^{a+1}f(x+n)\,dx=\int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx<\infty.$$
By the Monotone Convergence Theorem, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(x+n)$ is convergent
almost everywhere on $[a,a+1]$.

For the first question. consider an interval $I=[a,b]$, **not** containing zero.
Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{a}^{b}f(nx)\,dx
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\int_{na}^{nb}f(x)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x)f(x)\,dx$$
where
$$u(x)=\sum_{x/b\le n\le x/a}\frac1n.$$
Approximating $u(x)$ by the harmonic series,
$$u(x)=\log(x/a)-\log(x/b)+O(1)=\log(a/b)+O(1)$$
so is bounded. As before, MCT shows that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(nx)$ converges
almost everywhere on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't expect that MCT is applicable. It seems that it is quite useful when dealing with series.