# $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n}\int_{na}^{nb}f(x)dx<+∞$ $\Rightarrow$ $\int_0^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I would like to show that given $f:[0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous and non negative function so that exists $a<b$, $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n}\int_{na}^{nb}f(x)dx<+\infty$$

then $$\int_0^{+\infty}f(x)dx$$ converges.

I should try to cut the interval $[an, bn]$ in an intelligent way so that, later, I can use $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n}\int_{na}^{nb}f(x)dx$ as an upper bound for the wanted integral and a middle term in between, but I can't think of any.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the source for this question?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I'm trying to show that given a $f$ as in the problem if $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f(nx)$ converges $\forall x \in [0,+\infty)$ then $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converges as well. I've already showed that the convergence of the series implies the convergence of the first series of integrals in this problem

Comment: The following [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3237046/121671) answers this question as a tool to prove another related statement.

Answer (score 3):

First we'll use the monotone convergence theorem to write
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n \int_{na}^{nb}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\infty \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n\chi_{(na,nb]}(x)\right)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
where $\chi_A(x) \in \{0,1\}$ is $\chi_A(x) = 1 \iff x \in A$.

At this point, we'll focus on that sum.  Specifically,
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n\chi_{(na,nb]}(x) &= \sum_{n=\lceil x/b\rceil}^{\lceil x/a\rceil-1} \frac1n \\ &\geq \int_{\lceil{x/b}\rceil}^{\lceil{x/a}\rceil}\frac1t\,\mathrm{d}t \\ &= \ln\left(\lceil x/a\rceil/\lceil x/b\rceil\right) \\ &\to \ln(b/a)\quad \text{as } x\to\infty.
\end{align*}$$

Therefore, there is some $N$ such that $x \geq N$ implies $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n \chi_{(na,nb]}(x) \geq \frac12\ln(b/a)$$
In context, this means
$$\int_N^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \leq \frac2{\ln(b/a)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n \int_{na}^{nb}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x < \infty.$$

Comment: (+1) DavideGiraudo [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3237046/121671) solves this problem to prove another related  statement. I think however that your solution is much simpler.